# How do I negotiate for colo space?

Tags: colocation

I guess this isn't a technical question, but it definitely is something IT teams deal with, so here goes:

I'm looking at getting a rack at a local colocation facility. I'm weighing the options versus building out in a cloud platform. We are REALLY low bandwidth and power. There's a total of six hosts for the total operation. You can assume we use <= 10 amps of power and <= 2Mbps 95th percentile.

Do you have any advice for getting the best deal?

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep - say exactly this to them;

"I'm weighing the options versus building out in a cloud platform. We are REALLY low bandwidth and power. There's a total of six hosts for the total operation. You can assume we use <= 10 amps of power and <= 2Mbps 95th percentile."

Then tell them how much you want to pay - they'll bite your arm off.

With lots of people moving to 'cloud' services colo's are losing money, you're easy money for them, use that to your advantage.

Comment: +1.  Also look at both large national providers (e.g. rackspace.com) and smaller local providers.  Sometimes your local colo providers will offer better deals, and as a bonus you can drive to the datacenter to work on your servers when you hose something during an upgrade.